# How do I deploy only some of my controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following controllers:

1. Sales
2. Purchase
3. Accounts
4. Hr
5. Settings

I need to deploy or publish only the sales and the purchase controllers. How do I deploy only those?

Answer (score 1):

Well. You can't. All controllers in you project are included in a deploy.

What you can do is to remove the default route and create two specific routes, one for each controller that you want to enable access to.

To start with, find the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment it out and then create the specific routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Sales", // Route name
        "sales/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Sales", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
        "Purchase", // Route name
        "purchase/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Purchase", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: i already used user role based but some time if wrongly assumed to user. that module can be displayed

Comment: there is any option to choose controller wise or model wise

Comment: "role based"? are you talking about authorization? This is not authorization. It tells MVC which controllers it can use. They are two different things, Read about routes before you ask a new question.

Comment: sorry. i'm new to mvc. i am asking how to publish only sales and purchase controller not hr, accounts

Comment: Please read about routes in the asp.net homepage before asking anything else. ***understand*** my answer before you write another comment.

Comment: @SaravananArunagiri jgauffin is right. Don't try to look for any other answer on your question since this is the only possible answer. If you want to restrict access to certain parts of your application because they aren't ready yet you can for example block them with the help of routes.

Comment: Finally, i learning and got method 'Area'. there is a solution for my question. thank you @jgauffin

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative than creating specific routes for these controllers would be to block the routes you don't want access to via `IgnoreRoute`.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Block the controllers under development so they
        // cannot be accessed.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("accounts/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("hr/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("settings/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```